# Yodlee REST login - Invalid cobrand conversation credential

Tags: rest, yodlee

Following the [REST quick start tutorial](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Quickstart/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide) I am sending a request to `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login` with `login`, `password` and `cobSessionToken` just taken from the `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin` endpoint but I get this reply:

```
{
  "Error": [
    {
      "errorDetail": "Invalid cobrand conversation credentials"
    }
  ]
}
```

What could be the problem?
[Here you can see](http://cl.ly/image/1q2x0X3L2b2Z) the full details of my request in Postman
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check the cobSessionToken value in the request you have in PostMan after pasting? It seems like PostMan is trimming last character from cobSessionToken value which you are pasting from response of first call.

I am suspecting this is the issue, else if this is not the case then please try once in AdvanceRest Client.

Comment: You were right Apoorv. Using Postman "Raw response" when copy and pasting fixes the problem. Thank you for your time on this, this was quite a silly issue :( never had so many copy-paste crazy problems in such a small time window.